# ¿Cómo defino un umask permanente para unos usuarios en concreto?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-mint

Necesito establecer una `umask` diferente a la que viene por defecto en el sistema.

El "problema" es que no tiene que ser para todos los usuarios, sino para unos en concreto, y tengo entendido que si modifico el archivo “.bashrc” toca a todos.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Puedes agregar algo del código que has intentado?

Answer (score 2):

Sí, como dices se trata de indicarlo en el fichero `<home_del_usuario>/.bashrc` y añadir la línea del tipo:

```
umask 022
```

Así, cada vez que el usuario en cuestión abra la sesión, se le activará ese valor y solamente para él.